# how to access one JFrame to another class JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem.

I am creating two JFrames in different classes in the same package in eclipse. In the first JFrame class I have different JButtons for different uses.

In the first JButton, the name is "View user profile" after clicking this button some event is performed. the event occurs when the button is pressed that is another JFrame visible and this JFrame shows all user information which user is login. but this JFrame not show all the user details present in the database.

Because this showing an error for accessing another class (JFrame) variable like JButton, JLabel, etc.

Please help me.  How can I access different class variables in another class.

Comment: You can start providing code demonstrating the problem. A minimal valid example.

Answer (score 1):

> "please help me how can i accesss different class varible in another class."

First See [**The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/2587435)

I would instead use a modal `JDialog`. See [**How to make Dialogs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

To access the components in the GUI class, you can just pass it as reference to the `JDialog` class, with getters for the components you want to access.

Here's an example of what I mean. You can see the `JLabel` from the `GUI` class is accessed through the `getJLabel` method from the `GUI` class.

```
public class GUI {
    private JLabel label;
    private MyDialog dialog;
    private JFrame frame;

    public GUI() {
        JButtton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog = new JDialog(frame, true, GUI.this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public JLabel getJLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}

public class MyDialog extends JDialog {
    private GUI gui;

    public MyDialog(final JFrame frame, boolean modal, GUI gui) {
        super(frame, modal);
        this.gui = gui; 

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.addActionListener(MyListener());
    }

    private MyListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JLabel label = gui.getJLabel();
            label.setText("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```